# firebase.database set doesn't catch error on network failure

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, network-programming

**Problem:**
I have a very straightforward firebase issue. My `.catch` function is never triggered.

**Background:**
If the network is connected, I am able to successfully save to firebase and my `.then` function is called. However if I disconnect from the internet, the `.catch` is never called. I see network failures in the chrome dev tools. They just try and try to connect but never do (internet is disconnected).

```
firebase.database()
    .ref('password')
    .set("hat")
    .then(() => {
      debugger;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      debugger;
    })
```

Comment: If a client loses its network connection, your app will continue functioning correctly. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#write_data_offline

Answer (score 3):

**Answer:**
Lost network connection is not a failure state for Firebase.

**Background:**
According to their [Offline-Capabilities docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities)

> Firebase applications work even if your app loses its network connection temporarily.

I was able to verify that my `.catch` statement was working with other types of failures such as incorrect permissions.

**Workaround:**
My current plan is to manually implement a timeout that will fire if the network request hangs for too long.

Comment: can you show us how to implement your workaround?